# Why am I getting a 0x8000500c error when enumerating a SearchResultCollection in .Net

Tags: .net, directory, enumeration

I am trying to enumerate the values in a SearchResultCollection.

Everything compiles fine, but I get the 0x8000500c error on this line:

```
foreach (PropertyValueCollection e in de.Properties.Values)
{
    sw.WriteLine(e.Value);
}
```

Full method is below:

```
private static void GetValues()
{
    var directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://8.8.8.8:8888", "foo", "bar",
                                                       AuthenticationTypes.None);
    var ds = new DirectorySearcher(directoryEntry);
    var final = ds.FindAll();

    var sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\z\FooBar.txt");

    var titlesDone = false;

    foreach (var de in from SearchResult x in final select x.GetDirectoryEntry())
    {
        if (!titlesDone)
        {
            foreach (string d in de.Properties.PropertyNames)
            {
                sw.WriteLine(d);
                titlesDone = true;
            }
        }


        foreach (PropertyValueCollection e in de.Properties.Values)
        {
            //I get the error on the below line
            sw.WriteLine(e.Value);
        }
    }

    sw.Flush();
    sw.Close();
}
```

Can you help me figure out why this isn't working?

Thanks

Comment: I'd try replacing the `foreach` loop with a `while` loop (see [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx) for the transformation). Then let us know if the exception happens when calling `e.MoveNext()` or when accessing `e.Current`. If the latter, then you're in luck! You can swallow the exception and continue. But if the former, I don't know if calling `e.MoveNext()` again would let you skip the problematic item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Active Directory error codes are listed in the AdsErr.h SDK header file:

```
//
// MessageId: E_ADS_CANT_CONVERT_DATATYPE
//
// MessageText:
//
//  The directory datatype cannot be converted to/from a native DS datatype
//
#define E_ADS_CANT_CONVERT_DATATYPE      _HRESULT_TYPEDEF_(0x8000500CL)
```

So the problem is on the other end of the wire, there's some kind of unusual custom property in the directory entry that it doesn't know how to convert to a common data type.  Talk to the server admin to get this resolved or be more selective with the properties you need to read.