# Error 8000500c on accessing DirectoryServices Properties

Tags: .net, properties, directoryservices

I am a first time poster and I hope someone can help me out with this one.

I have a bit of code that does authentication against an LDAP server (I believe it is a Novell eDirectory) and then retrieves certain properties. This code works fine on Windows 2003, Windows 2008 and Windows 7, but when I run it on a Windows 2012 server (accessing the same LDAP store) it fails and throws an error 8000500c when it accesses the Property value. Interestingly, accessing some other properties such as cn works fine, just some properties (like groupMembership) that fail

Here's a code sample:

```
string ldapurl = "LDAP://<server>:389/cn=<user id>,ou=<ou value 1>,ou=<ou value 2>,ou=<ou value 3>,o=users";

DirectoryEntry oDirectoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry(ldapurl);
oDirectoryEntry.Username = <user id>;
oDirectoryEntry.Password = <password>;

// I have tried a few different Authentication Types 
oDirectoryEntry.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.FastBind;

DirectorySearcher oDirectorySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(oDirectoryEntry); 
oDirectorySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("groupMembership");

// This works
SearchResult oSearchResult = oDirectorySearcher.FindOne();

// This is where it throws the error
string sType = oDirectoryEntry.Properties["groupMembership"].Value.ToString();
```

Does anyone have any idea where I am going wrong here? Again, it works fine on Windows 2003, Windows 2008, and Windows 7 with .Net 3.5 and .Net 4.5 SP1 installed. It appears only to be a problem with Windows 2012.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why am I getting a 0x8000500c error when enumerating a SearchResultCollection in .Net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673555/why-am-i-getting-a-0x8000500c-error-when-enumerating-a-searchresultcollection-in)

Comment: Yes, there is indeed some duplication here with another post in that I get the same error. However, the problem I am experiencing only occurs on Windows 2012 while everything works fine on Windows 2008 and Windows 2003, which is what has me stumped. I will be happy to re-direct this query to the other post if that is the better thing to do.

Comment: We have worked out what the problem is. We found a hotfix for windows 2012 that deals with error 0x8000500c when using adsi to read an OpenLDAP Server. We have applied this hotfix and the problem is gone. This is the link to the hotfix: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2802148/en-us